# Why is appium complaining about namespaces not being declared?

Tags: java, selenium, groovy, appium

The below code is annoying me. Ive had this work before without hassle in a different IDE
`((AndroidDriver)appDriver).startActivity(new Activity("packageName", "packageActivity.itt.gui.ZoneWelcomeActivity"))`

Full error `org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: io.appium.uiautomator2.common.exceptions.UiAutomator2Exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Namespace with prefix 'packageName' has not been declared.`

I need to switch between 2 apps on the device and from what i know this is the only way to do it?

Comment: From the provided code, You added only activity name did you add actual app package name in the first argument? instead of "packageName" ?

Comment: I have renamed the packages for discretion purposes. It is a valid string taken from the apk package